# How to prepare the back button action to deal with infinite scroll?

Tags: infinite-scroll

Unfortunately my question is not fixing or understanding code. I have a problem with infinite scrolling, where the user can scrolldown `x` far, click on `xStory` and enter a new page. Then naturally hit back, and expect to return to `x`, but in my case users are returned to the "bottom", which is the height if whatever page they came from. But the page that the back button returns to has the default number of posts, and not however many were revealed by scrolling.

I'm looking for some conceptual ways to look at solving this. Of course real examples would be great!

I'm using the plugin [Infinite Scroll](http://wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll/) which operates on CSS selectors:
[image]

Comment: How precisely do you implement infinite scroll?

Comment: @Rarst Oops, updated the question.